# Rotation in Processing for objects that inherit from PVector

Tags: inheritance, rotation, processing

I have an issue in getting proper rotate() functionality in Processing when using it within objects that extend PVector. Below the code with examples. Blue rectangle should rotate around it's center (as others do) but it rotates around the origin (0,0) - why?

```
// coordinates rect 1
float xc;
float yc;

// coordinates rect 2
PVector position;

// rect 3
Shape shape;

// rect 4
ShapeInheritance shapeInheritance;

void setup() {
  size(200,200);

  xc = width *0.25f;
  yc = height * 0.5f;

  position = new PVector(width *0.75f, height*0.5f);

  shape = new Shape(width*0.5f, height*0.75f);

  shapeInheritance = new ShapeInheritance(width*0.5f, height*0.25f);

  rectMode(CENTER);
  noFill();
}

float theta = 0;

void draw() {
  theta +=0.01f;
  background(255);

  //rectangle 1 (black)
  pushMatrix();
  translate(xc,yc);
  rotate(theta);
  stroke(0);
  rect(0,0,50,50);
  popMatrix();

  //rectangle 2 (red)
  pushMatrix();
  translate(position.x, position.y);
  rotate(theta);
  stroke(255,0,0);
  rect(0,0,50,50);
  popMatrix();

  // rectangle 3 (green)
  shape.display();

  // rectangle 4 (blue)
  shapeInheritance.display();
}

class Shape {
  float shapeTheta = 0;
  PVector pos;

  Shape(float x_, float y_) {
    pos = new PVector(x_, y_);
  }

  void display() {
    shapeTheta += 0.01f;
    pushMatrix();
    translate(pos.x, pos.y);
    rotate(shapeTheta);
    stroke(0,255,0);
    rect(0,0,50,50);
    popMatrix();
  }
}

class ShapeInheritance extends PVector {
  float shapeTheta = 0;

  ShapeInheritance(float x_, float y_) {
    super(x_, y_);

  }

  void display() {
    shapeTheta += 0.01f;
    pushMatrix();
    translate(this.x, this.y);
    rotate(shapeTheta);
    stroke(0,0,255);
    rect(0,0,50,50);
    popMatrix();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `rotate()` for class PVector is different see [link](http://processing.org/reference/PVector_rotate_.html).

```
v = new PVector(10.0, 20.0);
println(v);  // Prints "[ 10.0, 20.0, 0.0 ]"
v.rotate(HALF_PI);
println(v);  // Prints "[ -20.0, 9.999999, 0.0 ]"
```

So you are changing the vector not projection matrix! You should use it out of class that inherit from PVector.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! So solution now is to keep reference to PApplet inside the ShapeInheritance and call applet.rotate() instead of rotate().